# How to prove the following identity regarding Laplace transforms?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I tried solving it by integrating by parts but i was unsuccessful.

> $${\cal L}\left[\int_0^xf(x-t)g(t)\ dt\right]=F(p)G(p)$$

Comment: Start from the right hand side.

Comment: @Nosrati i am getting  two integrals multiplied together.how to bring them in single one ?

Comment: by changing variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
F(p) G(p)
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-pu}f(u)\ du\int_0^\infty e^{-pv}g(v)\ dv \\
&= \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-p(u+v)}f(u)g(v)\ du\ dv  \,\,\, , \,\,\, \text{u+v=t} \,\, , \,\, \text{v=x}\\
&= \int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty e^{-pt}f(t-x)g(x)\ dt\ dx \,\, , \,\, \text{changing order of integration}\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-pt}\Big[\int_0^tf(t-x)g(x)\ dx \Big]\ dt  \\
&= {\cal L}(f*g)(t)
\end{align}